# Choose a folder where the file will be downloaded(REACTJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I have this snippet of code that returns a url containing a .csv file for download.

```
  const getCsvURL = async () => {
    const response = await FiltroDesempenhoManager.getCsvURL();
    setCsvUrl(response);
  };
```

This function is called from a click of a button.

```
    <Button
       href={csvUrl}
       onClick={() => getCsvURL()}
       ...
    />
```

I would like to open the explorer for the user to choose the folder in which the file will be downloaded. Currently the file is being automatically downloaded in the download folder. How do I do this? Button is from Material UI

Comment: You cannot do that. Browsers *always* allow the user to choose the download location, or else pre-configure it (like the "Downloads" directory).

Comment: Yeah, I was just about to write this is not possible: _"The download takes place normally"_.

Comment: I edited the last part @Pointy . I would like to open the explorer for the user to choose the folder in which the file will be downloaded.

Comment: @GiuseppeFantoni well unfortunately the browser user is in control: if the browser is configured to always save in the "Downloads" folder (or some other folder), you cannot force the browser to open a file save dialog.

Comment: i got it. tyy Pointy :)

Answer (score 1):

I use method window.showSaveFilePicker

```
async function downloadPNG() {
    try {
        const fileHandle = await getSaveFilePicker();
        const imageUrls = thumbnails.map((image) => image?.src);
        const url = imageUrls.join("");
        await save(fileHandle, url) 
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

async function getSaveFilePicker() {
    const opts = {
        suggestedName: fileName,
        types: [
            {
                accept: { "text/plain": ["." + fileType] },
            },
        ],
    };
    return await window.showSaveFilePicker(opts);
}

async function save(fileHandle, url) {
    try {
        const writable = await fileHandle.createWritable();
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const imageBlob = await response.blob();
        await writable.write(imageBlob);
        await writable.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To download a file with React.js, we can add the download attribute to an anchor element.

For instance, we can write:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <a
        href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
        download
      >
        Click to download
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We just add the download prop to do the download.

If we don’t want to use an anchor element, we can also use the file-saver package to download our file.

To install it, we run:

npm i file-saver

Then we can call the saveAs function from the package by writing:

```
import React from "react";
import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

export default function App() {
  const saveFile = () => {
    saveAs(
      "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf",
      "example.pdf"
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={saveFile}>download</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The first argument is the URL to download and the 2nd argument is the file name of the downloaded file.