# How to get selected folder path in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, directory

How can i get selected folder path in react. I want that because when user select folder, all downloads will be downloaded to the selected folder.

Comment: I've already answer similiar question please check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73648247/18393222)

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered a similar question. pleaee check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73648247/18393222)